# Joining 2 Queries or using result of on in second query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query which delivers categories of searched products depending on the search criteria

This means the query delivers all the categories whose products will be found under given search conditions.

the value of first query needed to be used in second like

```
    WITH
      sub_categories AS (
        select categories.left, categories.right
        from categories 
        inner join ...
        inner join ...


        where ....
      ),
      main_categories AS (
       SELECT * 
        FROM categories
        WHERE lft < 9 AND rgt > 10 
      )
SELECT *
  FROM main_categories 
  UNION 
  SELECT *
  FROM sub_categories
```

here in my `main_categories` I want to replace

```
WHERE left < 9 AND right > 10
```

with the values from `sub_categories` i mean 9 should be replaced with sub_categories.left or something like

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: requirement not cleared..

Comment: If you have columns named "left" and "right" in "categories" then you probably need to quote them since they seem to be keywords. F.e. `WHERE [left] < 9 and [right] > 10`

Comment: Just a note, please be more careful with spelling column names. In the first CTE you use `categories.left` and `right`, in the second it suddenly is `lft` and `rgt`. **Are these really different columns?** And then in the text you show it as `left < 9 AND right > 10` again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
 WITH
      sub_categories AS (
        select categories.left, categories.right
        from categories 
        inner join ...
        inner join ...


        where ....
      ),
      main_categories AS (
       SELECT * 
        FROM categories inner join sub_categories on categories.id=sub_categories.id
        WHERE lft < sub_categories.left AND rgt > sub_categories.right
      )
SELECT *
  FROM main_categories 
  UNION 
  SELECT *
  FROM sub_categories
```